# How can I get a offset amount so that my cubes snap flush together?

Tags: geometry, unreal-blueprint

I have these cubes. Each cube is built exactly the same, except for the last one where the pivot(0,0,0) is at the bottom. (cube D)

The goal is to get the cubes to snap together so that the faces are flush. What happens is when I move a cube (source) to the other (target), when they touch the connector(colored blocks- blue=Y, red=X, green=Z), my script gets the location for the target cube connector, and moves the source cube to that point. It places the pivot of the source cube at the target connector point.

In the attached YT video, you will see that when I snap them, the cubes intersect. This means I need to offset the snap location so that it doesn't intersect. OnScreen I print out the values of the Source and Target point.

How do I calculate the offset based on the axis that touch?

https://youtu.be/2PAX9XH8w9U

What I've tried is to subtract the pivot(usually 0,0,0) from the Source connector. This gives me the Offset, but i don't know how to apply it to the correct axis.

Answer (score 0):

Vector subtraction is most often used to get the direction and distance from one object to another. Place a scene component on the sides of you cube and subtract the center to find the distance.